# arranging mysql query latest post at bottom with pagination applied

Tags: mysql

i am facing tough time finding a way to sort database query result according to my needs. here is a database layout.

ID -- acc_id -- date so on...

1    12345     unix time ...

2    12345     unix time ...

3    12345     unix time ...

like this it goes on....

54    12345     unix time ...

55    12345     unix time ...

what am trying to do is fetch the latest 10 posts and sort it in desc order (by ID or date) so that the latest post will be at the bottom and oldest on top. this way the next 10 posts will be fetched through ajax in similar manner.

46  12345  date

47  12345  date

this way...

54  12345  date

55  12345  date

i cant figure out how to sort the query. can anyone show me ways to do so. i would appreciate your help :-)

Comment: please show your table structure..

Answer (score 0):

If you want the latest data at the bottom you should `ORDER BY ID ASC`, not `DESC`.

Comment: hi charlieco, but dont forget we are paginating the query to 10 each. in this case the latest post will be on top not at bottom. if ORDER BY ASC then first 10 posts (from ID:1 to 10 will be fetched). if i give a condition as: WHERE ID<20 AND ID>9 (suppose we have 20 entries) then i guess it will work but in this can i have to use sql_calc_found_rows. can anybody show me a short cut. Database design is very simple.